# JavaScript selected text position with respect to parent

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find the textual start and end of the selection.

My HTML structure is like this:

```
<div id="viewer">
<iframe id="epubjs-iframe:eb39fd66-ffb7-48b2-add9-a2764fc0ad74" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" style="border: medium none; visibility: visible;" s6745771569="true" replaced="true">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" style="overflow: hidden; width: 18825px; height: 496px; -moz-column-fill: auto; -moz-column-gap: 156px; -moz-column-width: 547px;">
<head>
`enter code here`<body style="margin: 0px; font-size: 100%;">
<p id="1_p_6" class="indent">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
</p>
</body>
</html>
</frame>
</div>
```

and I am using this JavaScript method:

```
function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
    var caretOffset = 0;
    var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
    var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
    var sel;
    if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
        preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
        preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
        caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
    } 
    return caretOffset;
}
```

In my case `preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);` is giving an error:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Range.selectNodeContents does not implement interface Node.
```

The working example is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/TjXEG/496/

Comment: couldn't reproduce the issue in my browser. Which browser and version you are using?? Technically this issue shouldn't exist since `HTMLDivElement` inherits from [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)

Comment: I am using latest firefox 31.0 and chrome Version 36.0.

Comment: did you check the fiddle gives you the error??

Comment: no fiddle in not giving this error.

Comment: then could you please show us a fiddle which actually reproduces the issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the proper solution.

```
function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(objectId, win)
{
    var startOffSet = 0;
    var endOffset = 0;
    var element = window.frames[0].document.getElementById(objectId);
    var parentInnerHTML = element.innerHTML.toString();
    var parentNodeArr = parentInnerHTML.split('');
    if(parentInnerHTML != "null"){
        var sel;
        if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined")
        {       
            var rangeIndex = 0; 
            var parentIndex = 0;
            var max = parentInnerHTML.length - 1;
            var range = win.getSelection().toString();
            var rangeNodeArr = range.split('');
            var rangeLen = rangeNodeArr.length - 1;
            for (parentIndex=0; parentIndex <= max; parentIndex++)
            {
                if(parentNodeArr[parentIndex] === rangeNodeArr[rangeIndex]){
                    if(rangeIndex === rangeLen){
                        break;
                    }
                    rangeIndex++;
                }else{
                     rangeIndex = 0;
                }
            }
            endOffset = parentIndex + 1;
            startOffSet = parentIndex - rangeIndex;
        }
        console.log("startOffSet: " + startOffSet + " endOffset: " + endOffset);
        return { startOffSet: startOffSet, endOffSet: endOffset };
    }else{
        console.log("Parent is null");
    }
}
```